# how to check device in which a web application is running on

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, node.js

I created a web app in node.js,express,angular and bootstrap and it had forms and everything so when i ran it on another device and the forms and zoom where all messed up. my question is how can we find out in which device my app is running say an iPad or a laptop and make changes accordingly
thanks,
Srihari

Comment: Is this what you required http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-mobile-device-in-jquery

Comment: yup that is what i required, thanks

Comment: You can find which type of mobile it is by using http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/ and check this link http://kmturley.blogspot.in/2013/12/detect-device-browser-and-version-using.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To recognize a device is not a good choice to go closer to the problem. There are too many. It is better to see whether the device supports the necessary functions. For this has been built https://modernizr.com/.

If you seem rather to be the problem that your application is not responsive. So the different resolutions does not adapt. May I suggest to learn something on the Web. https://www.smashingmagazine.com has mostly good articles to it.

Sorry I can not help you better, but without an example which does not go well, you can not get a better help.